# Version number in Nuget manager differs from one from properties window in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, version, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I don't understand why the version number for .NET Standard shown in Nuget Package Manager differs from

[image]

one shown in Properties Window.

[image]

In addition, the drop down list does not provide us with the version number shown in Properties Window. The list cannot be selected as well.

## Question

What is wrong with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here.

The .NET Standard 1.4 is the framework your project is targeting.

The .NET Standard Library NuGet 1.6.1 package is used by the .NET Core SDK you have installed. It defines the APIs that are available to your project based on the project's target framework. The 1.6.1 library supports all .NET Standard project's from 1.0 through to 1.6.

The version of the .NET Standard Library NuGet package is not expected to match the target framework of your .NET Standard library project. As of today there are only 3 versions of this NuGet package:

- 1.6.0
- 1.6.1
- 2.0.0

If you look inside the .NET Standard Library 1.6.1 NuGet package you will see different dependencies based on what your project's target framework is. There are different dependencies for:

- .NET Standard 1.0
- .NET Standard 1.1
- .NET Standard 1.3